# Golf to find Boring numbers

Tags: code-golf, number

If an integer has a digit/sequence of digits in it which repeats continuously (You will understand why I said "continuously") 5 or more times, we call It "Boring".

For example, `11111` is Boring, whereas `12345` is not.

## Instructions

Take an Integer as Input

Output a truthy value if the integer is boring, and a falsey value if the integer is not boring.

## Example

`11111`=>`true` or `1` (1 repeats 5 times)

`12345`=>`false` or `0`

`1112111`=>`false` or `0`

`4242424242`=>`true` or `1` (42 repeats 5 times)

`-11111`=>`true` or `1`

`3452514263534543543543543543876514264527473275`=>`true` or `1` (543 repeats 5 times)

If you use other types of "truth" and "false", specify it.

## Rules

Basic [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

Good luck!

Comment: Is `1112111` boring?

Comment: Is `4242424242` boring?

Comment: 4242424242 is boring.1112111 is not.

Comment: I guess today is the day of numbers no one likes. :)

Comment: 1/7*1000000=Boring

Comment: Is `111112` boring?

Comment: It is. It has `1` continuously repeating 5 times.

Comment: Only non-negative integers?

Comment: All integers including negative integers.

Comment: Should the truthy or falsy value be consistent?

Comment: No. Actually some answers already use non-consistent truthy values.

Comment: All of your boring examples consist *only* of the boring part. Could you add some test cases like `12333334` and `51231231231231236`?

Comment: Done. Its quite long.

Comment: @MatthewRoh Actually `1112111` contains more than the boring part

Comment: But It isn't boring

Comment: Strictly speaking, all numbers are boring, as they all can be written with an arbitrary number of leading zeros. :-)

Comment: "If you use other types of "truth" and "false", specify it." Can I use `false` as `true` and `true` as `false`?

Comment: Sure, but be sure to specify it.

Comment: You should have said without regex..

Comment: @MatthewRoh It's a really really easy challenge.

Comment: is pi boring in the region of the Feynman point?

Comment: Uhh, probably, I think?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

Code:

```
Œv¹y5×åO
```

Explanation:

```
Œ         # Compute all substrings from the input.
 v        # For each substring.
   y5×    # Repeat the substring 5 times (42 × 5 = 4242424242).
  ¹   å   # Check if it's in the input string.
       O  # Sum up the result. Non-boring numbers should give 0.
```

**Truthy** is non-zero and **falsy** is zero. Uses the **CP-1252** encoding.

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xZJ2wrl5NcOXw6VP&input=NDI0MjQyNDI0Mg)

Comment: Nice use combining `Œ` with `×`.

Comment: @Adnan Nice Work! c=

Comment: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6CTTw9MPLz284P9/I2MjIAAA) (although I realize that wasn't possible yet when you've posted your answer mid-2016).

Answer (score 23):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 9 bytes

```
(.+)\1{4}
```

[Verify all testcases!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JWAoLispXDF7NH0&input=MTExMTEKMTIzNDUKMTExMjExMQo0MjQyNDI0MjQy) (slightly modified to run all testcases at once.)

Comment: Wait, People are doing It THIS fast?

Comment: I was way too slow to post this. Knew Retina would love this challenge :)

Comment: @Emigna sorry xd

Comment: XD I actually did not expect people would do this fast.

Comment: Might be worth noting that this may print positive numbers other than `1` as well if the input is boring.

Comment: Why does `(.+){5}` not work?

Comment: @LuisMendo Doesn't that match any 5+ anything regardless if they're the same or not? For example it would match `12345`

Comment: @Emigna That may be it. I don't know enough about regexes

Comment: @LuisMendo `(.+){5}` expands to `(.+)(.+)(.+)(.+)(.+)` while `(.+)\1{4}` expands to `(.+)\1\1\1\1`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know it worked by just expanding

Answer (score 7):

## Java 8, 52 bytes

```java
s->s.matches(".*(.+)\\1{4}.*")
```

Outgolfed [this Java 8 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84750/52210) with a direct `String#matches`.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jU9LbsIwEN3nFKOsbKpYsuOQSojeoGxYQheDcVtDYkfYICGUs6fDT2JVsGeksd5nnjd4wCJ01m/W28E0GCN8ovOnDMD5ZHffaCzMzk@AVQiNRQ@GzdPO@R@IfEJAT00VEyZnYAYepjDE4iOKFpP5tZHlYsTEG18u5Un3YpTzYZKRotuvGlLchIfg1tDS7pv74gv5de/8GJNtRdgn0RGSGs@8MCyX55PzS4h/WKrU1XOWlOoVN63u9ym1eC0fpVOV1GpcVjTq8rHe6/EFIkqt61LV94/0WT/8AQ)

```java
s->              // Method with String parameter and boolean return-type
  s.matches(     //  Return whether the entire String matches the following regex:
    ".*          //   0 or more leading characters
     (.+)\\1{4}  //   group of 1 or more characters, repeated 5 times
     .*")        //   0 or more trailing characters
```

Answer (score 6):

## Java 8, <s>73</s> 66 bytes:

```
L->java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(.+)\\1{4}").matcher(L).find();
```

Hooray for Java 8 lambdas! Returns `true` if match is found and `false` otherwise.

[Try It Online! (Ideone)](http://ideone.com/bU1vbB)

Answer (score 4):

### Lua, 35 Bytes

Well, I don't see how to do better with Lua's patterns! Takes a command-line argument as input and output `nil` for falsy cases, and the number repeated when truthy.

```lua
print((...):match("(%d+)%1%1%1%1"))
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 16 bytes

In node.js (60 bytes)

```
process.stdin.on('data',t=>console.log(/(.+)\1{4}/.test(t)))
```

Wasting a *ton* of bytes on input/output.

JavaScript ES6 (33 bytes)

```
alert(/(.+)\1{4}/.test(prompt()))
```

Again wasting bytes on input/output.

Preferably, as an anonymous function (22 bytes)

```
n=>/(.+)\1{4}/.test(n)
```

Or even shorter (**16 bytes**)

```
/(.+)\1{4}/.test
```

Thanks @BusinessCat for pointing out my mistakes.

Comment: You can use `/(.+)\1{4}/.test(n)` instead of `match` which saves a few bytes. Also it doesn't look like this will actually output anything.

Comment: @BusinessCat You're absolutely right, I guess I missed that in the question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You needn't take standard input, you could use function arguments

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Method RegExp.prototype.test called on incompatible receiver undefined`. I'm not sure if that technically counts as a correct answer, wouldn't it need to be something like `/./.test.bind(/(.+)\1{4}/)`?

Comment: The question states that "any number repeated 5 **or more** times" is Boring.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3.5, <s>49</s> 43 bytes:

(*-6 bytes thanks to tips from [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)!*)

```
import re;lambda u:re.search(r'(.+)\1{4}',u)
```

Uses a Regular Expression to match all repeating sequences of characters as long as they repeat continuously 5 or more times. Returns an `re` match object (such as `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='4242424242'>`) if a match is found as a truthy value, and nothing or `None` as a falsey value.

[Try It Online! (Ideone)](http://ideone.com/I41iPz)

Comment: Ah, the almighty regex.

Comment: Replace `{4,}` by `{4}`?

Comment: @LeakyNun Yeah, that also works.

Comment: What's the `\1` do after the regex group?

Comment: @speedplane Matches any subsequent occurrences of the match from the group.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
$_=/(.+)\1{4}/
```

+ the `p` flag.

(run with `perl -pe '$_=/(.+)\1{4}/'`)

Thanks to Dom Hasting for the `(.+)` instead of `(\d+)`.

Explanations if needed :
  `(.+)` will match any part of the number, and `\1{4}$` searches if it is repeated 4 times consecutives.

Comment: Good one, but there are better golfers out there. Its still good though.

Comment: I'm not sure Perl can do better than that... And I still wanted to submit a Perl solution, so here it is.

Comment: Can you add an explanation?

Comment: I think you might need `$_=/(\d+)\1{4}/` instead as `111112` is boring but this won't catch it. You might even be able to use `/./` as per the Retina answer.

Comment: @DomHastings  Indeed, I read the question too fast and didn't see the "5 times" (and the examples don't show it clearly). You're right about the `/./`, I edited it.

Comment: No problem! I think you need to remove the `^` and `$` fully though, then you should be good!

Comment: Yup you're right, I was tring to match a "very boring number" when only boring ones were enough

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>13</s></sup> 11 bytes

```
§ṁ€ȯm*5tQda
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9DyhzsbHzWtObE@V8u0JDAl8f///7qGIAAA)

similar to 05AB1E.

-2 bytes from Dominic Van Essen and Jo King.

Comment: ...and you can use ```ȯ``` to get [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxhPrHzWtSTm089ziINOShzunpfz//9/QCAaNTQA)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen @JoKing Thanks for the help. Also, `Q` instead of `Ṗ` would be more accurate I think.

Answer (score 2):

### SABDT, 41 bytes

White Space-less:

```
if($.r("(.+)\1{4})"=""){pr"0";}el{pr"1";}
```

Prettified:

```
if( $.r( "(.+)\1{4}" ) = "" ){
    pr "0";
} el {
    pr "1";
}
```

Answer brought to you partly by the brilliant person who came up the regex "(.+)\1{4}"

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) without regex, 66 bytes

```python
lambda s:any(s[j:i]*5in s for i in range(len(s))for j in range(i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3PDsIgDIdfpcdi8DD@DEPik8wdMA5lmd0CXPb0CBqjbQ@/fl@Tbnt@rCSLP1/K4p7Xm4NkHe2YhtmG8aADQQK/RghQY3R0n3CZCBNjjc4/GhgrDVFDQ9eKd0IqzWsSbVPi2/z48dUK3SnRS12jkv9zMv1b1ROjjBRGjxa2GCijx5QjEqsfXw)

Answer (score 1):

### C# - <strike>93</strike> 38 bytes

```
s=>new Regex(@"(.+)\1{4}").IsMatch(s);
```

Takes a string, returns an integer.

Thanks to [aloisdg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15214/aloisdg) for saving a lot of bytes!

Comment: You can take the argument as a string though, which should save you some bytes.

Comment: Wouldn't `@"(.+)\1{4}"` work as the regex as well? Does in my C# environment at least.

Comment: You can use a lambda. It is allowed. `s=>Syst...`

Comment: @Emigna - it would definitely work regardless of the C# environment. Anything with >5 consecutive characters will also work for exactly 5 consecutive characters.

Comment: Did you forget "Text" in `System.Text.RegularExpressions`?

Comment: You can create a new Regex and use isMatch (returns a bool). Also if you update your regex to the Retina solution (the mighty one!). You can move to **69** bytes: `s=>new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(.+)\1{4}").IsMatch(s);`

Comment: Also, I think that we should be able to write `s=>new Regex(@"(.+)\1{4}").IsMatch(s);` Because we stay in .NET (which his our stdlib) and we never count for `using System.Linq;` or `using System.Collections.Generic`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

1 byte thanks to Maltysen.

```
sm}*5dQ.:
f}*5TQ.:
```

Truthy value is a non-empty array.

Falsey value is `[]` (empty array).

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%7D%2a5TQ.%3A&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%2211111%22%0A%2212345%22%0A%221112111%22%0A%224242424242%22&debug=0)

```
f}*5TQ.:   input as a string stored in Q
f}*5TQ.:Q  implicit arguments
        Q  input
      .:   all substrings of.
f   T      filter for this condition, keep those returning true:
  *5           repeat five times
 }   Q         in Q? (True/False)
```

Comment: get 8 bytes by replacing `m` with `f` and taking out the sum.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>46</s> <s>40</s> 36 bytes

```
b=a__;StringContainsQ[b~~b~~b~~b~~b]
```

Function. Takes a string as input and outputs `True` or `False`. Tests strings against the expression `a__~~a__~~a__~~a__~~a__`, which represents the same character sequence repeated 5 times. For reference, the shortest solution using a regex is 45 bytes long:

```
StringContainsQ@RegularExpression@"(.+)\1{4}"
```

<sup>*curse you RegularExpression!*</sup>

Comment: Nice use of pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>37</s> 33 bytes

thanks to NoOneIsHere, I forgot about `<?=`

program for PHP<5.4, prints `1` for boring numbers, `0` else

```
<?=preg_match('/(.+)\1{4}/U',$n);
```

usage:

- set `register_globals=1` in `php.ini` for php-cgi
  then call `php-cgi <filename> n=<number>;echo""`
- for PHP>=5.4, replace `$n` with `$_GET[n]`

**non-regexp solution, <s>152</s> <s>147</s> 140 bytes**

```
<?for($e=$n+1;--$e;)for($f=$e;$f--;)for($a=str_split(substr($n,$f),$e),$k=$c='';strlen($v=array_pop($a));)$c-$v?$k=0&$c=$v:($k++<3?:die(1));
```

- returns exit code 1 for boring numbers, 0 else
  replace `die(1)` with `die(print 1)` and append `echo 0;` to print instead
- same usage as above, but also set `short_open_tags=1` if disabled
- The outer loop got an unreasonable start value in the golfing, replace `$n+1` with `ceil(strlen($n)/5)+1` or at least with `strlen($n)` for testing or it may loop like forever.

Comment: `<?=preg_match`... is a few chars shorter

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 80 (63?)

It would be 63 if there were no import statement.

```
import Data.List
f x=or$tail[isInfixOf(concat$replicate 5 b)x|b<-subsequences x]
```

#### Usage

```
f "11111211"
f "11111"
f "12345" 
f "1112111"
f "4242424242"
f "-11111"
f "3452514263534543543543543543876514264527473275"
```

By the way, *consecutive* makes more sense to me than *continuously.*

(Sorry, I can't comment yet.)

Comment: I hope My upvote helped making yourself able to comment.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 22 bytes

```
q:T,{)Tew{5*T\#)}/}%:+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v9AqRKdaMyS1vNpUKyRGWbNWv1bVSvv/f2MTUyNTQxMjM2NTINPEGBlZmJuBpYBKzE3MjY3MTQE)

Takes sum of 1-indexed positions of all possible repeated substrings in the input. Returns 0 if interesting, anything non-zero if boring.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
øUã mp5
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=%2bFXjIG1wNQ&input=WwoiMTExMTEiIC8vdHJ1ZQoiMTIzNDUiIC8vZmFsc2UKIjExMTIxMTEiIC8vZmFsc2UKIjQyNDI0MjQyNDIiIC8vdHJ1ZQoiLTExMTExIiAvL3RydWUKIjM0NTI1MTQyNjM1MzQ1NDM1NDM1NDM1NDM1NDM4NzY1MTQyNjQ1Mjc0NzMyNzUiIC8vdHJ1ZQpdLW1S) (includes all test cases)

```
øUã mp5     :Implicit input of string U
ø           :Does U contain any element of
 Uã         :  Substrings of U
    m       :  Map
     p5     :    Repeat 5 times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Ṡs`, 34 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.25 bytes

```
K5*vc
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIg4bmgcz0iLCIiLCJLNSp2YyIsIiIsIjExMTExMTIyMjIyMiJd)
The 05ab1e answer but in less bytes :)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 77 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.some((_,i)=>s.some(c=>--i<0&&([,s]+1).split([t+=[,c]]+t+t+t+t)[1],t=''))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hcpBCsIwEEDRvQdpZkgyWOnS6bKXCEFKDBKJTXGC10@hokvlrz68@/yaJTzTWu1SrrFN3IRHISmPCHAxCb8XeLQ2nY9dB86I1z2SrDlVcFWzM8F7Xd@h672prBRiC2WRkiPlcoMJHBGp4fRJecTDD/EXDDtoGw)

Answer (score 0):

## TSQL, 151 bytes

Golfed:

```
DECLARE @t varchar(99)='11111'

,@z bit=0,@a INT=1,@ INT=1WHILE @a<LEN(@t)SELECT @z=IIF(@t LIKE'%'+replicate(SUBSTRING(@t,@a,@),5)+'%',1,@z),@=IIF(@=20,1,@+1),@a+=IIF(@=1,1,0)PRINT @z
```

Ungolfed:

```
DECLARE @t varchar(99)='11111'

,@z bit=0,
@a INT=1,
@ INT=1
WHILE @a<LEN(@t)
  SELECT
    @z=IIF(@t LIKE'%'+replicate(SUBSTRING(@t,@a,@),5)+'%',1,@z),
    @=IIF(@=20,1,@+1),
    @a+=IIF(@=1,1,0)

PRINT @z
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/509048/golf-to-find-boring-numbers)**

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 26 bytes

```
$args[0]-match"(.+)\1{4}"
```

I'm by no means a regex master, so credit to the other answers for that.

Answer (score 0):

## JS without regexes, 166

```
b=s=>{for(let i=0;i<s.length-4;i++){for(let n=1;n<=Math.floor((s.length-i)/5);n++){if([1,2,3,4].every(k=>s.slice(i,i+n)==s.slice(i+n*k,i+n*(k+1))))return 1}}return 0}
```

non minified:

```
// test any start pos, and length
var b = s => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= s.length - 5; i++) {
        for (let n = 1; n <= Math.floor((s.length - i) / 5); n++) {
            // test if s is boring at position i, with length n
            if ([1, 2, 3, 4].every(k => s.slice(i, i + n) === s.slice(i + n * k, i + n * (k + 1)))) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
};

console.log(b('11111'));
console.log(b('12345'));
console.log(b('1112111'));
console.log(b('-11111'));
console.log(b('3452514263534543543543543543876514264527473275'));
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PPCG! However, this can really be golfed more. You can remove just the extra whitespace for a much shorter code. Please either golf it more or delete.

Comment: I like the idea of avoiding regex. Replace(['boring','let','false','true']['b','','0','1']; that cut 20 characters

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 24 bytes

```
#(re-find #"(.+)\1{4}"%)
```

Uses clojure's falsey values of `nil`/`false` and truthy values for everything else. Specifically, `nil` when no match is found for false, and an array `[]` for true when a match is found like for 11111 then `["11111" "1"]` is true.

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 27 bytes

```scala
_.matches(".*(.+)\\1{4}.*")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sODkxJ9F4wU3L_KSs1OQSBd_EzDyFai4FhZLKglQFPwVbheCSosy8dAVbOwWn_Pyc1MQ8LqBsWWKOQp4VWH5paUmarsXueL3cxJLkjNRiDSU9LQ09bc2YGMNqk1o9LSVNiIqbH4H6UlLTFHKBVmgkFqUXWyk4FhUlVkZDbIjVtFIIzcssARoJsl9BoQAoWpKTp5GnoWQIAkqamhjiRsYmptjEDQ2NsOswMYJBLJK6uOwB2mJkamhiZGZsCmSaGCMjC3MzsBRQibmJubGROdRBtVy1EI8vWAChAQ)